# apache setting to open local files

Tags: apache, file, local

I want to open a local file in it's default program.

Here's the funny part:
a php page running on my fresh wamp install with thius html:

```
<A HREF="C:/www/rensa/files/John, Osaka food.avi">
```

will not open a file.

If I copy/paste all of the source code into a html file on my desktop then the link works.

ie, it has to be apache that blocks it from opening.

What do i need to change in the apache config to allow it to open local files in the default program?

Comment: Or, it could be your *browser* that stops this from happening.  I think that by default most browsers will not follow `file://` URLs from remote sites (where "remote" means "anything not a `file://` URL).

Comment: A link to a local path will _never_ even be seen by the apache http server. Because it is an http server...

Comment: There is some useful information [here](http://superuser.com/questions/103026/open-a-direct-file-on-the-hard-drive-from-firefox-file)

Comment: I'd even say that `C:/www/rensa/files/John, Osaka food.avi` certainly isn't a _valid_ URL... `C:/www/rensa/files/John%2C+Osaka+food.avi` would be valid. Or maybe `C:/www/rensa/files/John%2C%20Osaka%20food.avi`.

Comment: I've tried using file:// as well, but the result is the same.

If it is a browser issue, then how come the exact same html works on the desktop, but not in my alias folder?

Comment: thanks, arkascha, I'll try it

Comment: nope, tried renaming it to "a.avi" and still didn't work.

Comment: the really interesting thing is that i can't even download the file if I right click - it saves it as "a.avi.txt" and then just an empty file